# c# Image processing Detect - save and match ROI

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, roi

I have a image processing project to work on it on C# with [emguCV](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and [openCV](https://opencv.org/) with Microsoft SQL Server. Our production line is like this;

[image: 1]

My products shows like this. I want to detect just the phone as ROI* and save it on my server.

[image: 2]

While the production is going on I want to process the images and if the image is not fully seen pass the image

[image: 3]

When the product is seen well (maybe its rotated) process the image, get the ROI, match the ROI with saved before. If there is not differences a lot want to save the product to server.

[image: 4]

I researched on edge detection, filtering but I didn't success to get the ROI.

---

*ROI: [region of interest](https://climserv.ipsl.polytechnique.fr/documentation/idl_help/Overview_of_Working_with_ROIs.html)

Comment: @spektre could you help me to find the point for starting

Comment: user:2521214 @2521214  did you show my post?